# Proving $\mathbb R[x]/\langle 1+x^2\rangle$ $\cong$ $\mathbb C$ without using 1st isomorphism theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, extension-field, group-isomorphism

I've seen many the proofs of  this by making use of First isomorphism theorem,
by considering the map,$$\phi:\mathbb R[x]\rightarrow\mathbb C$$ defined by $\phi(a+bx)=a+bi$.

My **questions** are

> - Why these proofs consider ($a+bx$) as the only form for the memebers of $\mathbb R[x]$?
> - Why they are not using ($a+bx+cx^2$) or ($a+bx+cx^2+dx^3$) or any other polynomials of degree greater than 1?

Is there any other proof of this without making use of First isomorphism theorem?

Thank you!!

Comment: Perhaps you'd prefer to define the map the other way, then: $\psi(a+bi)= a+b x$. Proof works just as well that way.

Comment: The direct answer to your question, though, is to note that we know what happens to $x^n$ since $\phi(x^n)=\phi(x)^n$, i.e. since $\phi$ is a ring hom.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom:then what will be the kernel of  ϕ?

Comment: It may be more natural for you to think of this map as meaning "plug in $x=i$".

Comment: Actually, I was mistaken in my first comment: that map doesn't work since it's not a hom.

Comment: @PKStyles: So far you have asked 32 questions, but have only accepted 3 answers, despite that fact that considerably more of the answers that you have received deserve acceptance. If you keep behaving like this, people will begin avoiding you and stop answering your questions. Please think about this.

Comment: @AlexM.:Sorry,but i don't know rules of MSE.I rarely use MSE.I'll take care of this in future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation $\phi(a+bx) = a+bi$ is given along with the assumption that $\phi$ is a homomorphism. This allows you to calculate, for instance, $\phi(a + bx + cx^2) = \phi(a + bx) + \phi(cx^2) = \phi(a+ bx) + \phi(cx)\phi(x) = a + bi + ci^2 = a - c + bi$. In fact, you only really need to specify $\phi(x) = i$ together with the fact that $\phi$ is a ring homomorphism to know the value of $\phi$ for every element of $\mathbb R[x]$.

You don't have to use the first isomorphism theorem, since you can just write down the isomorphism between $\mathbb R[x]/(x^2+1)$ and $\mathbb C$ and then verify that it is in fact an isomorphism.

Comment: :ϕ(f(x))=f(i),Will it work?

Comment: Yes. You should be able to prove this with the definition of a homomorphism.

Comment: :ϕ((f+g)(x))=(f+g)(i)=f(i)+g(i)=ϕ(f(x))+ϕ(g(x)),is it correct?

Comment: That's not quite what I meant, but yes, you've shown that your formula defines an additive homomorphism. What I meant was to show that that formula is equivalent to the one given in your original question.

Answer (score 0):

Because in the quotient $x^2=-1$, so every equivalent class has a representing belong to set of polynomial of degree at most $1$